# Unable to locate various OpenCV dependencies

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get OpenCV installed on my Pi 3. I'm following the instructions [here](https://blog.piwheels.org/new-opencv-builds/), and one of the things it says is to install various dependencies.

In particular, I'm trying to run:

```
apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
  libatlas3-base libsz2 libharfbuzz0b libtiff5 \
  libjasper1 libilmbase12 libopenexr22 libilmbase12 \
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libavcodec57 libavformat57 \
  libavutil55 libswscale4 libqtgui4 libqt4-test libqtcore4
```

The problem is that when I do that I get all kinds of package not found errors.

```
E: Unable to locate package libjasper1
E: Unable to locate package libilmbase12
E: Package 'libopenexr22' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libilmbase12
E: Package 'libavcodec57' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package libavformat57
E: Unable to locate package libavutil55
E: Unable to locate package libswscale4
```

I thought `apt-get update` was supposed to get the most up-to-date package lists and fix these sorts of problems. Are these packages simply not available for download at all? I find that hard to believe. I've tried this on both Stretch and Buster, and I get the same results.

Here is the same thing reproduced in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.7.7-buster
# Got the image from here:
# https://hub.docker.com/r/arm32v7/python/

# Install OpenCV dependencies
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
  libatlas3-base libsz2 libharfbuzz0b libtiff5 \
  libjasper1 libilmbase12 libopenexr22 libilmbase12 \
  libgstreamer1.0-0 libavcodec57 libavformat57 \
  libavutil55 libswscale4 libqtgui4 libqt4-test libqtcore4

# Install the OpenCV Python package
RUN echo [global] >> /etc/pip.conf
RUN echo extra-index-url=https://www.piwheels.org/simple >> /etc/pip.conf
RUN pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a bad `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. The original, broken contents looked like this:

```
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20200224T000000Z buster main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian-security/20200224T000000Z buster/updates main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main
# deb http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20200224T000000Z buster-updates main
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
```

I was able to find the packages when I changed the contents to look like this:

```
deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi firmware
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian buster main contrib non-free rpi firmware
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian buster main
```

My guess is that the original docker image base of `arm32v7` was designed for devices other than just the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.